# Which could be the best backbonejs tutorial for beginners

Tags: backbone.js, javascript-framework

I am very interested in backbone.js. But when I am learning, there's a lot of confusion in creating the structure. Could anyone show me a simple tutorial with good examples?

This will be very useful to all new learners.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Any online tutorial/basic tutorial to understand the framework structure for good start up. Need to follow a good/best structure without any confusion.

Comment: [Backbone.js Beginner Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZSjvWtUxYk) from @Thomas Davis is perfect way to start.

Comment: Hackr has a good compilation of some of the best Backbone.js tutorials - http://hackr.io/tutorials/backbone-js

Comment: Yes, this falls under "off topic" as far as a strict interpretation of the rules.  However, it was extremely helpful to me.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Hi these are some of the links from my bookmarks

- [Hello Backbone.js](http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/)
- [A Guide to Writing Backbone Apps at Coursera](http://blog.pamelafox.org/2013/07/a-guide-to-writing-backbone-apps-at.html)
- [Backbone Model Unit Testing with Jasmine](http://flippinawesome.org/2013/04/08/backbone-jasmine/)
- [BUILDING LARGE BACKBONE APPLICATIONS](http://victorsavkin.com/post/59496656297/building-large-backbone-applications)

And finally some real code [ToDoMVC-backbone_node_mongo](https://github.com/jamesor/todomvc/tree/939bf7a47d297562cfb61c453320dea281e24e83/labs/architecture-examples/backbone_node_mongo)

Comment: [backbone-js-wine-cellar-tutorial-part-1-getting-started](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/backbone-js-wine-cellar-tutorial-part-1-getting-started/)

Answer (score 17):

A complete tutorial/book: [Developing Backbone.js Applications](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/)

Comment: This is excellent. By far exactly what I've been looking for!

Answer (score 2):

I am ok with the below tutorials as i dont want to go with ebooks. These has nice overview of backbonejs folder structure and tutorials for beginners.

http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/

https://blog.andyet.com/2010/oct/29/building-a-single-page-app-with-backbonejs-undersc/

Thanks.